# Mounted share on Windows server is R/W from other Windows machines, but RO from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, windows, mount, share

I'm trying to access a Windows 2008r2 server share from a Raspberry Pi. 
On the Pi, I'm using the command

```
    sudo mount -t cifs -o user=username,password=******** //192.168.1.1/ShareName /mnt/REMOTE
```

Where ShareName  is shared as R/W on server 192.168.1.1, username and password are valid and have R/W rights to ShareName on server, and directory REMOTE has been created on Raspberry Pi  in /mnt

Windows machines have R/W access to ShareName using these credentials.

The Raspberry Pi can access the shared drive, but any write fails with "Permission Denied".

Why?

Comment: I addressed these issues in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60035/how-can-i-easily-access-windows-shares-from-the-rpi3 and never had that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimentation and hints from [this article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=125427), I found a working solution.  Two things are needed.  Create the Pi's mount point in /home/pi instead of /mnt, and add uid and gid credentials for user pi to the mount command. Presumably they would need to change accordingly if your user account on the Pi is different than 'pi':

`mkdir /home/pi/REMOTE
chmod 666 /home/pi/REMOTE
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=username,password=********,uid=pi,gid=pi //192.168.1.1/ShareName /home/pi/REMOTE`

Comment: You are right about the mount point.  However, the creds in the mount command are purely Windows, as I point out in my post.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.