# How can I easily access Windows shares from the Rpi3?

Tags: networking, pi-3, windows, mount, share

I have a Rpi3 which has been set up from 32gb NOOBS, and has VNC and XRDP installed so I run it headless via Windows Desktop Client on a Vista laptop.

On the laptop I have an explicit share of the C: drive called c.  (Of course, there is an implicit equivalent called c$ built into Windows - they work the same except mine shows up under Networks in Windows Explorer on the other networked Windows computers)

I want to access my Windows C:/ drive share on the Rpi3.

The IP address of my DEV laptop is 192.168.5.213 and the share name is c

**Question:  What is the easiest way to access Windows shares from Rpi3?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Utilize Microsoft's Common Interface File System (cifs) - the core of Microsoft's LAN Manager.

**(You can safely skip this tech info and proceed with the steps listed below)**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939973.aspx

```
The Common Internet File System (CIFS) is the standard way that computer
users share files across corporate intranets and the Internet. An enhanced
version of the Microsoft open, cross-platform Server Message Block (SMB)
protocol, CIFS is a native file-sharing protocol.

Some of the platforms that CIFS supports are:
    Microsoft Windows 2000, Microsoft® Windows NT®, 
    Microsoft® Windows® 98, Microsoft® Windows® 95
    Microsoft® OS/2 LAN Manager
    Microsoft® Windows® for Workgroups
    UNIX
```

### PROCEDURE:

Install cifs-utils

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Create a generic mount point under your login.

Add a directory for this particular share.

Perform the link

```
mkdir ~/LANPC
mkdir ~/LANPC/DEV
sudo mount //192.168.5.213/c /home/pi/LANPC/DEV -o username=Myname,password=Mypassword
```

Verify that it worked:

```
ls ~/LANPC/DEV
```

To make a local copy of, for instance, your Arduino sketches and libraries, you can do something like this:

```
mkdir ~/Arduino     
cp -r ~/LANPC/DEV/Users/SDsolar/Documents/Arduino ~/Arduino
```

---

This creates a a temporary link.  It will be lost when you reboot.

For persistent shares, append a line to the /etc/fstab file in this format:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/fstab

//192.168.5.213/c /home/pi/LANPC/DEV cifs username=Myname,password=Mypassword,iocharset-utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

You can add as many as you like, but be sure to create a mount point directory for each beforehand.

---

It you reboot the Rpi3 and find the share directories empty, issue this command:

```
sudo mount -a;
```

This will mount all the Windows shares you have appended to /etc/fstab

---

### --EDIT for new information on persistent share connections.

In this question, [My Windows share will not mount during boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13882/my-windows-share-will-not-mount-during-boot), @Cary posted an answer that deserves mention:

In Raspbian,

```
Click "Menu" button 
Select Preferences
Select Raspberry Pi Configuration 
In the System tab there is an option called "Network at Boot"
Check the "Wait for network" box
Click "OK"
```

This will allow for any slow-connecting networks such as WiFi.

---

### --EDIT for new information on how to show shares on the desktop:

```
Right-click on the desktop
Select Preferences
Select Desktop Icons
Check the box that says "Show connected volumes on the desktop"
```